# Collapsible List with + and - sign is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the Script i have written to handle it but for some reason + and - swapping is not happening

```
$('.showCheckbox').click(function(e) {
    var dynamicBox = $(this).attr('val');
    var collapseSign = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+dynamicBox).slideToggle();
    $('#'+dynamicBox+collapseSign).html(function(_, text){
        return text === '+' ? '&#8722;' : '+';
    });
});
```

You can find Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7Gt4L/ Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `collapseSign` portion of your selector should be a string. Otherwise you will be trying to match something similar to `#partnerspartnerscollapseSign`, which doesn't exist:

```
$('.showCheckbox').click(function(e) {
    var dynamicBox = $(this).attr('val');
    $('#'+dynamicBox).slideToggle();
    $('#'+dynamicBox+'collapseSign').html(function(_, text){
        return text === '+' ? '&#8722;' : '+';
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/7Gt4L/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$('#'+dynamicBox+collapseSign).html(function(_, text){
    return text === '+' ? '&#8722;' : '+';
});
```

to:

```
$('#'+collapseSign).html(function(_, text){
    return text === '+' ? '&#8722;' : '+';
});
```

This will use the ID of the collapse sign clicked to change the text.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gt4L/4/)

Comment: This doesn't work if the title is clicked instead of the sign.

Comment: That is a good point and something I hadn't noticed, your solution is better as it covers that.

Comment: That was the reason i joined two ids :) anyways thanks @oGeez i Was stuck for a hour!